# Class members of another class

Tags: c#, class, .net-3.5

I have following class structure

```
 public class Limit
 {
    public double MinSelectedValue;
    public double MaxSelectedValue;
    public double MinValue;
    public double MaxValue;

 }

public class Limits
{
    public Limit Standard;
    public Limit Critical;
    public string Name;
    public string Unit;

}
```

I want to have a generic List of class Limits. My question is how to assign values to variables of type 'Limit' in class Limits.

Thanks 
Vivek

Comment: I'd make those fields into properties. Probably even readonly properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you are using Java language so this answer was related to java language.

Suppose you define list like this way

```
List<Limits> mylimits = new ArrayList<Limits>();
```

and you want to assign the the value of the Limit object into the Limits class. First define the Limit class object

```
Limit standard = new Limit();
Limit critical = new Limit();
```

now define the Limits class object like way

```
Limits limits1 = new Limits();
limits.Standard = standard; // or you can directly define here like limits.Standard = new Limit()
limits.Critical = critical;
```

now add this limits object to the list like this way

```
mylimits.add(limits1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoping the Code you have given in C# language, in C# you can assign the values to variables of type as a class like follows.

```
        Limits Lmt = new Limits();
        Lmt.Standard = new Limit
        {
             MinSelectedValue = 23.5,
             MaxSelectedValue = 20.20,
              MinValue = 1.23,
               MaxValue = 23.2
        };
        Lmt.Critical = new Limit
        {
             MinSelectedValue = 23.5,
             MaxSelectedValue = 20.20,
              MinValue = 1.23,
               MaxValue = 23.2
        };
```